How do I use levels and factors to fit a dataset into the levels I've made and create a histogram of the frequency within the levels?
I am working paleo data in which I have pulled information from the database on a genus level and have found the unique labels of genera within a certain dataset and their respective age ranges.
Each unique genus has a corresponding age range which is most cases fits the numerics of more than one level. I have had the idea of taking the minimum and maximum value and assigning each of those to levels respectively because everything in between those two must also be within the range. However if I did that would I be able to assign the middle values to their respective levels and add a count for each bin//level it meets the criteria for?
I saw other questions with levels that were discussing factors. What are factors and do I need to utilize them in this scenario?
Note, I am very new to R and don't have a large background in many coding concepts.
I created a set of 102 levels within the overall age range of all of the organisms in the dataset. Each of these levels correspond to subranges within the whole. I also have pulled each of the distinct genera and have their corresponding age ranges. I'm unsure how to proceed from here.
Below is a simple example what I am trying to accomplish. I want to take the age ranges of the "genera_df" and assign them to levels 1-6 and in most cases they should be assigned to multiple levels within the factor but not always. For example GenusE only fits the range for Level 6 which GenusA fits within the range of Level_3 Level_4 Level_5 and Level_6. The last part which I have not attempted requires me to create a count of individual genera in each level (Ex: Level_1 has 1 genus, Level_2 has 1 genus which is the same one as in level 1, Level_2 should have 2, etc.)
Range_age <- 0:300

# example genera and age ranges
genera_df <- data.frame(
  Genus=c("GenusA", "GenusB", "GenusC", "GenusD", "GenusE"), 
  Start_Age_Ma=c(300, 200, 150, 250, 300), 
  End_Age_Ma=c(100, 150, 0, 100, 250)
)

# Print the dataframe
print(genera_df)

#Levels 
Ages <- cut(Range_age, breaks=c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300), 
            labels=c("Level_1", "Level_2", "Level_3", "Level_4", 
                     "Level_5", "Level_6"))


I think this does what you want, or at least close enough that you can adapt it the rest of the way.
I make consecutive integers corresponding to each label, and then classify the start and end ages as those integers, and then fill in the sequence between the integers in a list class column. Then I can get the string labels, unnest the data into a regular column, and count the results.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
age_breaks = c(0,50,100,150,200,250,300)
age_ints = 1:6
age_labs = paste0("Label_", 1:6)

short_result = genera_df |>
  mutate(across(ends_with("Age_Ma"), 
    \(x) as.integer(cut(x, age_breaks, labels = age_ints, include.lowest = TRUE, right = FALSE)),
    .names = "{.col}_level"
  )) |>
  mutate(
    labels = mapply(seq, End_Age_Ma_level, Start_Age_Ma_level),
    labels = lapply(labels, \(x) age_labs[x])
  )

short_result
#    Genus Start_Age_Ma End_Age_Ma Start_Age_Ma_level End_Age_Ma_level                             labels
# 1 GenusA          300        100                  6                3 Label_3, Label_4, Label_5, Label_6
# 2 GenusB          200        150                  5                4                   Label_4, Label_5
# 3 GenusC          150          0                  4                1 Label_1, Label_2, Label_3, Label_4
# 4 GenusD          250        100                  6                3 Label_3, Label_4, Label_5, Label_6
# 5 GenusE          300        250                  6                6                            Label_6

long_result = unnest(short_result, labels)
long_result
# # A tibble: 15 × 6
#    Genus  Start_Age_Ma End_Age_Ma Start_Age_Ma_level End_Age_Ma_level labels 
#    <chr>         <dbl>      <dbl>              <int>            <int> <chr>  
#  1 GenusA          300        100                  6                3 Label_3
#  2 GenusA          300        100                  6                3 Label_4
#  3 GenusA          300        100                  6                3 Label_5
#  4 GenusA          300        100                  6                3 Label_6
#  5 GenusB          200        150                  5                4 Label_4
#  6 GenusB          200        150                  5                4 Label_5
#  7 GenusC          150          0                  4                1 Label_1
#  8 GenusC          150          0                  4                1 Label_2
#  ...

long_result |> count(labels)
# # A tibble: 6 × 2
#   labels      n
#   <chr>   <int>
# 1 Label_1     1
# 2 Label_2     1
# 3 Label_3     3
# 4 Label_4     4
# 5 Label_5     3
# 6 Label_6     3


Generally I'd take the values computationally from the data rather than hard-coding them.
> (age_range <- range(genera_df[2:3]))  ## a range has two values: min and max
[1]   0 300
> (age_breaks <- c(0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300))
[1]   0  50 100 150 200 250 300
> (age_breaks <- seq(from=age_range[1], to=age_range[2], length.out=7))  ## maybe better
[1]   0  50 100 150 200 250 300
> (age_levels <- seq_len(length(age_breaks) - 1L))  ## using only numbers is more practical
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

Then I'd define following cut_levels() function,
> cut_levels <- \(x, y, age_breaks.=age_breaks, age_levels.=age_levels) {
+   cut(age_breaks[age_breaks > y & age_breaks <= x],
+       breaks=age_breaks., 
+       labels=age_levels.,
+       include.lowest=TRUE) 
+ }

that works like this,
> cut_levels(genera_df$Start_Age_Ma[1], genera_df$End_Age_Ma[1])
[1] 3 4 5 6
Levels: 1 2 3 4 5 6

and put it in Map which can take the age columns as vectors.
> genera_df |> 
+   transform(
+     levels=Map(cut_levels, x=Start_Age_Ma, y=End_Age_Ma)
+   )
   Genus Start_Age_Ma End_Age_Ma     levels
1 GenusA          300        100 3, 4, 5, 6
2 GenusB          200        150          4
3 GenusC          150          0    1, 2, 3
4 GenusD          250        100    3, 4, 5
5 GenusE          300        250          6

To compute how the levels are populated, just unlist the levels (because it's a list column) use table(),
> (freq <- table(as.integer(as.character(unlist(genera_df$levels)))))

1 2 3 4 5 6 
1 1 3 3 2 2 

and barplot it.
> barplot(freq, xlab='Level', ylab='Frequency', col='blue', border=NA)


Notes: cut() already converts to a factor, read the in the manual what a factor is, in the console type ?factor. Make sure, you understand the difference between a bar chart and a histogram.
